# Collect signature with React Native Expo

Tags: expo

Does anyone know of a good library to use to collect a signature in Expo in both iOS and Android?

I've googled the heck out of it and tried half a dozen libraries but none seem to work well with Expo.

The closest one I've come across is https://github.com/brentvatne/signature-example but that works well on its own, but then has a bunch of issues when I bring it into my project.

Comment: What does 'has a bunch of issues' mean?

Comment: The problem I'm having with the example I posted seems to only work with expo's ex-navigator.  I was hoping to just drop it into the project I'm working on, but that uses React Navigation.  I can't seem to figure out why the navigator would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I use `react-native-signature-pad` and it works great for me. Here's the link :
https://github.com/kevinstumpf/react-native-signature-pad

Example :

````
import SignaturePad from "react-native-signature-pad";

  _signaturePadError = (error) => {
    console.log("Error", error);
  };

  _signaturePadChange = ({ base64DataUrl }) => {
    this.setState({ signature: base64DataUrl });
  };

    <SignaturePad
    onError={this._signaturePadError}
    onChange={this._signaturePadChange}
    dotSize={2}
    style={{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    }}
    />```
````

Comment: I believe this package has become deprecated as it requires deprecated packages from react native. I get errors and it does not run.